# How to find out all the sizes of GB of directories under the home directory?

Tags: bash, disk-usage, macos

On the Bash on a Mac, It is possible to do something like

```
cd         # go to home directory
ls -d */
```

to get the name of the folders in the home directory.

And we can use

```
du -sh Documents
```

to get the size in human readable form the size of the folder.

I tried something like

```
ls -d */ | xargs du -sh
```

but it won't work, due to some directories having the name `Tmp Files` (two words separated by a space), which made it `du -sh Tmp Files`.

Can this be modified or is there a simpler way to `du -sh` all top level folders and perhaps with a grand total?

Comment: I didn't know `*/`... it seems it is to expand all directories only

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the xargs:

```
du -sc */
```

Using `xargs` would only be useful if you have several thousands directories to avoid a "command line too long" error (but then would would not have a full total, only partial totals for each invocation of `du` by `xarg`).

Trick for other commands, to avoid the mis-parsing file names by `xargs`, have them separated by nulls instead of spaces or line feeds:

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 du -s
```

(`printf` will loop over its arguments and print them with a NUL at the end and `xarg` will split on the NULs due to its `-0` option). This assumes that the `printf` is a shell built-in (bash), using the binary would have the usual line length limit.

Answer (score 1):

The grand total would be

```
du -s .
```

and the sizes of individual folders (and possible files)

```
du -s * .*
```

only the folders

```
du -s */  .*/
```

Comment: can you perhaps add what it means by `*/`? Is it the same as on Bash and Zsh?

Comment: ah, `du -csh *` and `du -csh */` works well too, to show a grand total at last